# how to purge opengl shader cache

Tags: c++, winapi, opengl, caching, shader

current opengl drivers use compiled shader cache located in
c:/users/name/appdata/roaming/amd|nvidia/glcache/...

unfortunately, it causes program crashes almost every time i change some of the shaders, which i currently fix by manually deleting the shader cache.

the question is, is there any good way of purging the cache when i ship new version of the program? any opengl extension to control the caching? or some magical api from the operating system? or, at least, a proper way to find the folder?

another question: what keys do the drivers use to identify individual shaders? so that i can somehow change the key every time i change a shader.

Answer (score 3):

> unfortunately, it causes program crashes almost every time i change some of the shaders, which i currently fix by manually deleting the shader cache.

If that is happening there's something seriously broken with your system and/or your drivers' installation. This must not happen and if it does then it's not something a OpenGL program should have to concern itself with.

> another question: what keys do the drivers use to identify individual shaders?

Usually some hash derived from the shader source AST (i.e. just adding a whitespace or renaming a symbol will not do the trick).

> the question is, is there any good way of purging the cache when i ship new version of the program?

Not that I know of. Shaders are a "black box" in the OpenGL specification. You send in GLSL source text, it gets compiled and linked and that's it. Things like a shader cache or the internal representation are not specified by OpenGL.

> any opengl extension to control the caching?

Nope. Technically vendors could add a vendor specific extension for that, but none did.

> or some magical api from the operating system?

Nothing officially specified for that.

> or, at least, a proper way to find the folder?

Again nothing about this is properly specified.

Comment: it happend on my computer (amd gpu) and on my friend's computer (nvidia), and one more. thus i assume that it is not os nor driver related. if it is not a common problem, as you state, that leaves me with problem in my shader loading/compiling/linking code, right? i do extensively check for any errors, also i test it with debugging context and error callback set, and no errors. what would you suggest next? should i edit the question and add the loading code?

Comment: @Tomas: Yes, seeing your shader loading code would help. Also a backtrace of the crashed state of your program would help: Compile in debug mode and run with a debugger. Visual Studio offers a stack trace window, in GDB you can use the "backtrace" command. You're not going to see what's happening in the driver, but you can see which steps your program took that led up to the crash.